# Migrate core Date field with two values

Tags: migrations, 9

I have a content type on a D7 site that has a Date field with two values, "from" and "to". I have the same content type on a D9 (9.4.1) site. It also has a Date field with two values. When I try to migrate content from the D7 to the D9 site, the "from" value comes over, but the "to" value does not.

I have tried every solution I can find on this forum and others, but with no success.

Devel shows that the "from" value on the source site is field_date[und][0][value] and the "to" value is field_date[und][0][value2].

The two corresponding indices on the destination site are field_date[0][value][date] and field_date[1][value][date].

It should be a simple matter of migrating field_date[und][0][value] to field_date[0][value][date] and field_date[und][0][value2] to field_date[1][value][date].

The following will migrate the "from" date, but not the "to" date.

```
field_date:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: field_date
      process:
        value:
          plugin: format_date
          source: value
          from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
          to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
```

But how do I get the second date (whose source is "value2") to be included in the migration? Is there some way to specify that "value" is field_date/0/value/date and then modify that to field_date/1/value/date for the second one?

Comment: Your field type is date range right?

Comment: No, when I look at the Manage Fields tab for the content type, that field's type is listed as "Date" in both the source and the destination. Allowed number of values is set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are wrong properties of date range field. Try with config

```
field_date:
-
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_date
  process:
    value:
      plugin: format_date
      source: value
      from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
      to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
    end_value:
      plugin: format_date
      source: value2
      from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
      to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that didn't change anything. Additionally, I've discovered that using `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` for `to_format` causes the data for the first value not to be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a hint from MrD's answer above, I solved the problem by replacing the Date field on my destination site with a Date Range field. The final block on the migration configuration for this field is:

```
field_conference_dates:
-
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_date
  process:
    value:
      plugin: format_date
      from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
      to_format: Y-m-d
      source: value
    end_value:
      plugin: format_date
      from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
      to_format: Y-m-d
      source: value2
```

That worked. I suppose that I could have eventually made the Date field work, but this was a lot less effort.